# Angular validator and two-way binding problem

Tags: angular, angular-material

My source code can be accessed through the following link:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-umszww

I have set up the two-way binding for both division and system fields.
I click the "Add New Calltree", a modal popup and then 
For example, I select "A1" from the division drop-down box.
After that, I enter "ABC" to the System field,
finally, I click the "Save" button.

I expect the console should show the following:

```
CallTree {division: "A1", systemName: "ABC"}
```

However, the console should show the following actually:

```
CallTree {division: "A1", systemName: ""}
```

I have tried select other value in the drop-down box, the division value changes accordingly,
however, the systemName value does not change accordingly, would you tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of your form would be in `this.myForm.value` and NOT in `this.callTree`

Your save function should look something like this:

```
save() {
  if (this.myForm.valid) {
    console.log(this.myForm.value);
  } else {
    this.validateAllFormFields(this.myForm);
  }
}
```

> Here's the [**Working Sample Code**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g2czli?file=src/app/call-tree-editor.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: I have set-up a two-way binding for both fields already.
Why the division field works and the system field does not?

Comment: But doing that would be an anti-pattern if you're using a reactive form. The Reactive form takes care of syncing the model and your view on its own. So you don't really have to set that explicitly. As soon as you did `formControlName` it was done for your form out of the box.

Comment: Do you "the model" means the myForm object not the callTree object?

Comment: Yes. You are just setting the initial value of the form controls using the `calltree`. It's not bound two ways. If you make any changes in the form, it won't reflect in the calltree.

Comment: @TheKNVB, check the stackblitz once and try setting `division` as `A1` and `systemName` as some string value in the `CallTree` class. Once you do that, as soon as you open the modal, you'll be able to see the form getting pre-populated with A1 and that string value. But if you change that value, it won't reflect in `calltree`. Using `[(ngModel)]` could be an option, But then you're using `[(ngModel)]` just for two way data-binding which the Reactive Form would already have if you use the `myForm.value` property. So in all seriousness, using `[(ngModel)]` makes absolutely no sense at all.

Comment: OIC, I am self-learning student, so some of these concepts are not clear. Thank you for your introduction.

Comment: I'd highly recommend you to read more about Reactive Forms in Angular first. That way it would be much easier for you to understand it. I actually have **[a Free YouTube playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rHr473C7l3I&list=PLUcSYK_mU4eAfVRbJyHXRJKAzR666LTrc)** that you can go through to learn Angular. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204805/discussion-between-the-knvb-and-siddajmera).

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get value into `this.callTree` object than

you just have to replace your save function

```
save() {
     if (this.myForm.valid) {
      Object.assign(this.callTree,this.myForm.value);
      console.log(this.callTree);
    } else {
        this.validateAllFormFields(this.myForm);
    }
  }
```

Hope this will useful for you.

let me know if you want to know more.

thanks

Comment: I have set-up a two-way binding for both fields already. Why the division field works and the system field does not?

Comment: ok replace 
[(value)]="this.callTree.systemName"
to
[(ngModel)]="this.callTree.systemName"
it will work as you want

Comment: let me know if it dosen't

Comment: and also I want to know why you are using reactive form?

Comment: I have tried it, but it prompts this is depreciated solution. In fact, I am a beginner, I just copied from the official site. Some concept is still not clear.